# SnapBridge won’t upload files

Tags: nikon, snapbridge

I can’t get certain files to upload to SnapBridge from my P1000. I have made sure the firmware is up to date, but files I can see on my camera are not available to select for upload. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look at the [online manual](https://downloadcenter.nikonimglib.com/en/products/363/SnapBridge.html), and it says:

Images That Cannot Be Uploaded

- RAW images cannot be uploaded.
- AVI format movies (COOLPIX A300 movies) cannot be uploaded.
- For cameras with internal memory, images saved in the camera's internal memory cannot be uploaded depending on the camera.

There's an additional online help guide which seems to have even more [details of unsupported formats](https://nikonimglib.com/snbr/onlinehelp/en/03_transfer_03.html).

Comment: Thank you, I’ll look into that